# ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE for Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

What it the equivalent of `ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE` in Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `MIMETYPE` in Xamarin.Android is mapped to the `InterfaceConsts` class:

```
Android.Provider.ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype
```